# PHP echo-ing content as page loads

Tags: php, apache, http

So I'm doing some experimenting with PHP/Apache.
Let's say I have this code.

```
<div>DIV 1</div>
<?php sleep(2); ?>
<div>DIV 2</div>
<?php sleep(2); ?>
<div>DIV 3</div>
<?php sleep(2); ?>
<div>DIV 4</div>
<?php sleep(2); ?>
```

For some reason on my local apache webserver all the data appears in the browser at once, after all 4 sleep()s have been executed (8 seconds).

However if I run it on my host's server, the data is echo-ed to the browser in real time.
As in... div1 appears, after 2 seconds div 2 appears etc.

Why is that? Is this some setting in Apache?

Comment: It's buffering and caching through several layers and devices, which you cannot and should not attempt to control to any large degree of certainty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it may be a setting in php.

In you local server, output_buffering is enabled in your php.ini file.

You can disable it by setting :

```
output_buffering = off
```

To Ensure that the content is sent to the browser each time a echo-like statement is used, add :

```
implicit_flush = on
```

You also can set the buffer size by giving output_buffering a value.

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

here the buffer size would be 4KB.

Output buffering tells php to keep in memory all data to be sent to the browser until it encouters a flush() instruction in your code, the buffer happens to be full, or it is the end of the script.

Here is the full reference for output buffer from php.net : [php output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)

Comment: oh sorry, my english ! I meant 4KB.

Comment: You were right output buffering was on. I disabled it but it still does the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: just to double-check, is apache restarted ?

Comment: if you phpinfo() what does it tell you about the option ?

Comment: you may need to add "implicit_flush = on" in your php.ini

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Weird thing though, I checked my host's phpinfo() and they have implicit_flush = off but it still works.