# Send html during php page loading

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP echo-ing content as page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396630/php-echo-ing-content-as-page-loads)

I have a php page that has to load a heavy table, so after the page request there is a lot of time to wait.

Is it possible to send the page initially empty and, during the php page loading, send to the client the results, so one can see what has been loaded so far? (not a loading bar).

Comment: Yes, read about php output buffering

Comment: Related: [what is output buffering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's called [flushing the document early](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/05/18/flushing-the-document-early/). At its simplest, output some amount of HTML, and then calling `flush();`. As with most things, the devil is in the details of exactly what and when things would happen.